# reset root mysql on windows

Tags: mysql, reset, forgot-password

Following the recommended instructions for resetting root at [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-windows) and the other recommendations here at stackoverflow. I tried to reset my root pass both ways suggested, with and without the --defaults-file option

**First I tried.**

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld"  –init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt --console
```

**Error:**

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld: Too many arguments (first extra is 'ûinit-file=C:\mysql-init.txt').

**Next I tried**

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\my.ini" MySQL55 –init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt --console
```

**Error:**

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld: Too many arguments (first ex
>   tra is 'MySQL55').

'Too many arguments' makes me think my syntax is the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at your command lines again and manually delete the LONG HYPHENS.  Then type the hyphens in again manually.

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" –init-file=C:\mysql-init.txt --console
```

should be

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" --init-file=C:\mysql-init.txt --console
```

(notice the hyphens before `init-file`)

Refer to [mysqld options](http://kb.askmonty.org/en/mysqld-options-full-list)

Comment: I manually typed it in and got unknown option i.  How do you guarantee the short hyphen?

Comment: I edited the answer. When you type in overly-helpful programs like Word/Outlook (which are not meant for console commands), they lenghten out the dash. It is still normally visually discernable.

Comment: Thank you for your keen eye.   I manually typed it in with out the --default-file and used --init but all typed in the console.  Thanks Richard!

Answer (score -1):

1. I uninstalled the MySQL server.
2. I went to the mysql folder, and erased everything (the folder too).
3. Reboot the PC.
4. Reinstall the MySQL.
5. Set the new password.